# How can I use the command prompt through a c# app to convert an image?

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using MagickImage to convert images from my command prompt. However, it does not work when I try to use the same command with a c# process. Any ideas why that may be?

Here's my code:
`private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
// TO DO: Get the input and output paths for the file
string input = opnfd.FileName;
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);

// TO DO: Initiate the process for using the Magick CLT
using (Process Magick = new Process())
{
    // TO DO: Give the process the propper filename, argument and properties
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;

    // use a process to get the parent directory of the image
    string parent = Directory.GetParent(input).ToString();
    
    string command = String.Format("convert {0}{1} -resize 256x256 {2}\\output{3}", name, richTextBox1.Text, parent, comboBox1.Text);

    info.WorkingDirectory = parent;
    info.Arguments = command;
    Magick.StartInfo = info;
    if (Magick.Start()) MessageBox.Show("Conversion successful");
    else MessageBox.Show("Conversion failed");
    Magick.Close();

}

// command: convert INPUT -resize 256x256 OUTPUT
// example: convert Xbox_Controller.png -resize 256x256 C:\Users\Costin\Desktop\output.ico
```

}`

I am trying all of this in a Windows Forms App. With .NET 6,0 (since it has LTS). I have windows terminal set as the default terminal, but I don't think that affects it, since running it from cmd through the terminal still works. My ImageMagick version is ImageMagick-7.1.1-15-Q16-x64.

Comment: Good developers do not use terms like "it doesn't work" when trying to solve a problem. They explain what exactly happens, what they expected to happen, and any additional details about what they were able to find out about what was unexpectedly happening.

Comment: Got it.
So basically, the program gets all the details it needs to do the conversion. The problem is that when it starts, something makes it so the command's expected output (the converted image) does not appear. At least not in the directory it is supposed to.

Comment: You probably want to look at and use [WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=net-7.0). Also, there are Nuget packages that let you use ImageMagick directly from C# code, so you don’t need to spawn processes like that.

Comment: I know, the .NET library, I have it, but I didn't see anything like the convert method, so I thought I could use this.
Also, thank you for the advice, I will make sure to look into using WaitForExit for optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, you should provide more detail than just "it doesn't work", including what have you tried and what is the outcome you see.

I had a look at your script with some assumptions (such as that you appear to be using the OpenFileDialog), and noticed 2 things: you do not seem to specify ImageMagick anywhere in this, and your command string seems a bit odd.

I've made minor changes to your code that would work:

```
    // TO DO: Get the input and output paths for the file
    string input = opnfd.FileName;
    string inputFileName = Path.GetFileName(input);
    // string parentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(input);         an alternative to below on getting the path to the directory

    // TO DO: Initiate the process for using the Magick CLT
    using (Process Magick = new Process())
    {
        // TO DO: Give the process the propper filename, argument and properties
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "magick";           // <- you can just specify the imagmeagick directly here
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        // use a process to get the parent directory of the image
        string parent = Directory.GetParent(input).ToString();

        string command = String.Format("convert {0} -resize 256x256 {1}{2}output{3}", inputFileName, parentDirectory, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, comboBox1.Text);

        info.WorkingDirectory = parent;
        info.Arguments = command;
        Magick.StartInfo = info;

        if (Magick.Start()) MessageBox.Show("Conversion successful");
        else MessageBox.Show("Conversion failed");
        Magick.Close();

    }

    // command: convert INPUT -resize 256x256 OUTPUT
    // example: convert Xbox_Controller.png -resize 256x256 C:\Users\Costin\Desktop\output.ico
```

Please note here, that you previously used:

```
info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
```

Instead of specifying the cmd, you can directly specify the program you want to run. E.g. if you have the environment variable set for ImageMagick, you can just specify "magick" which will call the utility, or else provide the full installation path to ImageMackig. In this example I assume the environment variable is available and used:

```
info.FileName = "magick";   // or the full path, @"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16\magick.exe"
```

If you do want to keep it to "info.FileName = "cmd.exe", then you **MUST** make sure that you start your command string with **/C**, which instructs the shell to execute the provided string as a command. In that case you must also make sure, to add the program (ImageMagick) to your command string, such as below:

```
string command = String.Format("/C magick convert {0} -resize 256x256 {1}{2}output{3}", inputFileName, parentDirectory, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, comboBox1.Text);
```

But you do not need this, if you directly specify the program in the startInfo.

Otherwise, I am not sure why you attempted to get the file name without the file extension, but you can use Path.GetFileName(input) to get just the filename with the extension (e.g. Xbox_Controller.png), and I added an example to use Path.GetDirectoryName(input) to get the actual path to the folder where the file is.

I adjusted your command string slightly, and you may have to tweak it further as it was not fully clear how you intended to instruct it. Essentially it now takes the filename with extension, and provides the path of the folder where the input file resides with the default folder separator for the OS and adds the desired target file extension at the end (which appears to come from a ComboBox).

All that said, as others have already shared there are also existing Nuget packages and it may make sense to further improve the code with using .WaitForExit() etc. to ensure the process finishes accordingly.

Comment: You sir, are a life-saver. I don't know how the fact that I never mentioned magick in the command escaped me, but thank you.

Comment: No worries, it happens - let's be honest, many times the issues we troubleshoot for hours turn out to be one tiny oversight that we took for granted, lol! :-)